# How to bypass Do Not Disturb and allow alarm to go off when running a timed workout session in Swift and Watchkit

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, apple-watch, healthkit

I’m building an app that allows user to set a timer/alarm for a workout session in `HealthKit`. But the problem is, if the user has turned on the "Workout Do Not Disturb" option on the Watch app, it won't allow the alarm to notify the user that the timer has elapsed once the workout session has started.

Is there a way for my `Watchkit` app to bypass "Do Not Disturb"? So the alarm will go off when the timer has elapsed?